# Jmeter passes steps and not print to consul

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am facing an issue that I could not understand how to resolve.
I created a test plan that need to connect DB and count the results.
The problem is that Jmeter not perform any validation afterwards, I created a JSSR223 in the JDBC request and just want to print the results and Jmeter not print.
I created another sampler to print the DB results and still Jmeter not printing.
Jmeter just passes this steps, 
In the results tree I saw that it connects to DB and failed in the assertion, but why it passes the other steps? and just moving to debug sampler?
I can not print the results, I can not perform any debug since it is just black box.
can someone please advise? 
you can see in yellow all the steps that Jmeter not performed and just not exists in the results tree.

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0Lv.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get used to check *jmeter.log* file, it normally contains information regarding what went wrong, you should be able to figure out the root cause by looking into the log file. If you are not - update your question with *jmeter.log* file contents (at least essential parts)

My expectation is that your `${Conv_sense}` variable is not defined (or cannot be cast to [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)). Double check whether it is defined or not using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) listener combination.

---

Also don't refer JMeter Variables like `${Conv_sense}` in Groovy scripts body, use `vars.get('Conv_sense}')` instead, otherwise it might conflict with Groovy [GStringTemplate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) resulting in undefined behavior.